# python reading data from file

Tags: python

I have a file that contains:

```
        weight  height(ft)
John    240 5.3
Adam    300 6.1
Tom 140 6.9
Bob 135 4.6
Dan 170 5.5
Kang    190 5.9
Tong    167 4.1
Seth    120 6.7
Zoe 110 4.9
Watt    190 5.1
```

I am trying to:

1. Find BMI for all of them
2. Find the person whose BMI is highest, output person’s name
3. Find the person whose BMI is lowest, output person’s name.
4. Find persons who are underweight.
5. Find persons who are overweight.

This is what I have so far:

```
import math

def makeMagnitudeList():
    quakefile = open("Book1.txt","r")
    bmilist = [ ]
    namelist = [ ]
    for aline in quakefile:
        vlist = aline.split()
        namelist.append(vlist[0])
        namelist.append(((float(vlist[1])) / (pow(float(vlist[2])*12,2)))*703)  
        bmilist.append(namelist)           
    quakefile.close()
    return bmilist

mag = makeMagnitudeList()

maxmag = max(mag)
maxIdx = mag.index(maxmag)

minmag = min(mag)
minIdx = mag.index(minmag)

print(maxmag)
print(maxIdx)

print(minmag)
print(minIdx)
```

Comment: i want the names and integer all as the same index.

Comment: right now now is print like: ['John', 41.71116648866739, 'Adam', 39.35993908447551, 'Tom', 14.355644239072086, 'Bob', 31.14662098298677, 'Dan', 27.435720844811755, 'Kang', 26.64663730090331, 'Tong', 48.499983475444516, 'Seth', 13.05041954407069, 'Zoe', 22.36625942894164, 'Watt', 35.66203169721048]

Comment: Buddy remember that The more details you add, the more better answers you get! Add details as to what is wrong with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, in lines 9 and 10, you append the name of one person, and then their BMI, to `namelist`. So now you have

```
namelist = ['John', 41.71116648866739]
```

After that, you append `namelist` to `bmilist`, giving you

```
namelist = ['John', 41.71116648866739]
bmilist = [['John', 41.71116648866739]]
```

Now you repeat the process:

```
namelist = ['John', 41.71116648866739, 'Adam', 39.35993908447551]
```

Except that now when you append `namelist` into `bmilist`, you're appending a *reference* to the `namelist` object, not just its current *state*. What this means is, both times you append `namelist` into `bmilist`, you're always referring to the current value of the `namelist` object:

```
bmilist = [['John', 41.71116648866739, 'Adam', 39.35993908447551], [['John', 41.71116648866739, 'Adam', 39.35993908447551]]
```

Notice how you have two references to the `namelist` object in there now?

You can check this behavior like so:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = []
>>> b.append(a)
>>> a.append(4)
>>> b.append(a)
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

---

So how do you fix it?

Well, you can either reassign `namelist` an empty list at the beginning of each iteration:

```
def makeMagnitudeList():
    ...
    for aline in quakefile:
        namelist = []
        ...
```

OR, you can use a dictionary instead:

```
def makeMagnitudeList():
    quakefile = open("Book1.txt","r")
    bmidict = {}
    for aline in quakefile:
        vlist = aline.split()
        bmidict[vlist[0]] = float(vlist[1]) / pow(float(vlist[2])*12,2)))*703
    quakefile.close()
    return bmilist
```

---

P.S. What version of Python are you using? If 3.x, then you can eliminate the `float()` calls, since `/` won't truncate results. If 2.x, use `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file (after your hashbang/shebang if you have one) to get the same behavior:

```
from __future__ import division

import math

def makeMagnitudeList():
    ...
    for aline in quakefile:
        ...
        bmidict[vlist[0]] = vlist[1] / (703 * (12 * vlist[2]) ** 2)
```

Actually, you can even further simplify this:

```
        bmidict[vlist[0]] = vlist[1] / (101232 * vlist[2] ** 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is great for data management, replace math with numpy. Using pandas DataFrame objects as follows...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(path + "Book1.txt")


def makeMagnitudeList(df = df):
    bmilist = list()
    namelist = list()
    weight = np.float64(df['weight'])
    height = (np.float64(df['height(ft)'])*12)**2
#    print(weight,height)
    bmi = (weight / height) * 703
#    print(weight[0], height[0])
#    bmi = (weight[0] / height[0]) * 703
#    print(bmi)
    return pd.Series(bmi,dtype=np.float64,name='bmi')

bmi_column = makeMagnitudeList(df)
df_bmi = pd.concat([df.ix[:,:],bmi_column],axis=1)
print(df_bmi)
print('\n')
min_bmi = df_bmi.ix[np.argmin(df_bmi['bmi']),:]
max_bmi = df_bmi.ix[np.argmax(df_bmi['bmi']),:]
print('Minimum bmi:')
print(min_bmi)
print('\n')
print('Maximum bmi:')
print(max_bmi)
```

Returning the following output:

```
   name  weight  height(ft)        bmi
0  John     240         5.3  41.711166
1  Adam     300         6.1  39.359939
2   Tom     140         6.9  14.355644
3   Bob     135         4.6  31.146621
4   Dan     170         5.5  27.435721
5  Kang     190         5.9  26.646637
6  Tong     167         4.1  48.499983
7  Seth     120         6.7  13.050420
8   Zoe     110         4.9  22.366259
9  Watt     190         5.1  35.662032


Minimum bmi:
name              Seth
weight             120
height(ft)         6.7
bmi           13.05042
Name: 7, dtype: object


Maximum bmi:
name              Tong
weight             167
height(ft)         4.1
bmi           48.49998
Name: 6, dtype: object
```

Comment: This code gives the same bmi results. I tried to keep enough of the original to easily translate.